# Fresh Lucee 5.2.7.63 install unable to connect to fresh MySQL 8 install

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

I recently setup a new AWS server to be used as a web server for some small utility apps.  It's running Windows 2012.  I then:

- Installed Chrome
- Installed Lucee 5.2.7.63 using installer
- Installed MySQL 8.0.11 Community Edition using installer
- Installed MySQL Workbench
- Created a new schema via MySQL Workbench (which connects to MySQL just fine)
- Created a datasource in Lucee server administrator which fails verification with:

  ```
  Could not create connection to database server.
  ```

I tried using both a Lucee specific user, and the root user, and neither worked.  When I checked the Lucee error log I saw this occur several times, once for each verification attempt:

```
    Wed Jul 18 19:52:08 UTC 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

My guess is that I either need to force Lucee to use SSL, or force MySQL to allow a non SSL connection.   Unfortunately, the Lucee administrator has no option related to SSL and doesn't allow me to modify the connect string manually.  And I'm unsure how to alter settings for MySQL as I can't seem to find a my.ini file anymore.

The last time I setup a server was with MySQL 5.7 and I had no problems from start to finish, so I assume this must be a MySQL 5.8+ issue, but that is contradicted by the error message.

**Update**

In the end I decided to uninstall MySQL 8 and install MySQL 5.7.  It was difficult to download the installer for 5.7 (I got 8 again the first time for some reason), and then there was a conflict with the MySQL installer, that didn't want to recognize the 5.7 I downloaded, but after getting through it all Lucee began connecting immediately with no problem.

I would still be interested in a solution, though, so that I can use MySQL 8 in the future.

Comment: Have you tried another MySQL driver? I think I once read a thread in the CFML Slack about a similar issue, and the solution involved changing the driver version helped with MySQL 5.8.

Comment: @Twillen Thanks.  I tried downloading the MySQL 8 Java connector and got it running with Lucee.  However, I got an error message about the cert store.  Google informed me that the solution to that was to reinstall Lucee.

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining the datasource in your Application.cfc which will give you more control over the connection parameters. For example:

```
this.datasource = {
 database: "mydatabase"
 ,type: "mysql"
 ,host: "hostname"
 ,port: 3306
 ,username: "myusername"
 ,password: "encryptedpassword"
 ,custom: {
   useSSL: false
   ,useUnicode: true
   ,characterEncoding: "UTF-8"
 }
};
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  Unfortunately, after an hour of fiddling this still didn't work.